# how to make inputs work well with special characters using the locale.h library?

Tags: c, io, localization

> for some reason the function setlocale(LC_ALL, "English") doesn't work when using an input function,(getchar, scanf, fgets,..), to get a special character, (Ç, ã, õ, é,...).

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <locale.h>

    int cont = 0;
    int soma = 0;
    char resposta;

    int main (void){
    
        int i = 0;
        char caractere;
        struct cadastro {
            char cpf[20];
            int idade;
            char sexo;
            char nome[100];
        };
    
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
        
        void grauRisco (void);
    
        struct cadastro paciente;
    
        printf ("Faça o cadastro \n");
        printf ("Digite seu cpf: \n");
        scanf (" %s", &paciente.cpf);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf ("Digite seu nome completo: \n");
        do {
            caractere = getchar();
            paciente.nome[i] = caractere;
            ++i;
        } while (caractere != '\n');
        paciente.nome[i - 1] = '\0';
        fflush(stdin);
        printf ("Digite sua idade: \n");
        scanf (" %i", &paciente.idade);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf ("Digite seu sexo: m- masculino, f- feminino \n");
        scanf (" %c", &paciente.sexo);
        fflush(stdin);
        system("cls");
    
        printf("CPF: %s \n", paciente.cpf);
        printf ("NOME: %s \n", paciente.nome);
        printf ("IDADE: %i \n", paciente.idade);
        printf ("SEXO: %c \n", paciente.sexo);
    
        printf ("Responda as perguntas para saber qual ala deve-se dirigir \n");
        printf ("Tem Febre? s-sim, n-nao \n");
        grauRisco();
        printf ("Tem dor de cabeça? s-sim, n-não  \n");
        grauRisco();
        printf ("Tem secreção nasal ou espirros? s-sim, n-não  \n");
        grauRisco();
        printf ("Tem dor/irritação na garganta? s-sim, n-não  \n");
        grauRisco();
        printf ("Tem tosse seca? s-sim, n-não \n");
        grauRisco();
        printf ("Tem dificuldade respiratória? s-sim, n-não  \n");
        grauRisco();
        printf ("Tem dores no corpo? s-sim, n-não  \n");
        grauRisco();
        printf ("Tem diarréia? s-sim, n-não  \n");
        grauRisco();
        printf ("Esteve em contato, nos ultimos 14 dias, com um caso diagnosticado com COVID-19? 
    s-sim, n-não  \n");
        grauRisco();
        printf ("Esteve em locais com grande aglomeração? s-sim, n-não  \n");
        grauRisco();
        system("cls");
    
        printf ("Total de pontos %i \n", soma);
        if (soma <= 9) {
            printf ("Seu risco para Covid-19 é BAIXO. Dirija-se para à ala de risco baixo.");
        } else
            if (soma > 9 && soma <= 19) {
                printf ("Seu risco para Covid-19 é MEDIO. Dirija-se para à ala de risco médio");
            } else
                if (soma >19) {
                    printf ("Seu risco para Covid-19 é ALTO. Dirija-se para à ala de risco alto");
                }
            
        FILE *arquivo;
        arquivo = fopen ("pacientes.txt","a");
        fprintf (arquivo, "---------------------------\n");
        fprintf (arquivo, "CPF: %s \n", paciente.cpf);
        fprintf (arquivo, "NOME: %s \n", paciente.nome);
        fprintf (arquivo, "IDADE: %i \n", paciente.idade);
        fprintf (arquivo, "SEXO: %c \n", paciente.sexo);
        fprintf (arquivo, "Total de pontos %i \n", soma);
        fprintf (arquivo, "---------------------------\n");
        fclose (arquivo);   
    
        return 0;
    }

    void grauRisco (void) {
    
        scanf (" %c", &resposta);
        fflush(stdin);
    
        switch (resposta) {
            case 's':
                cont = cont +1;
            
                if (cont == 1) {
                    soma = soma + 5;
                } else 
                    if (cont == 2) {
                        soma = soma + 1;
                    } else
                        if (cont == 3) {
                            soma = soma + 1;
                        } else
                            if (cont == 4) {
                                soma = soma + 1;
                            } else
                                if (cont == 5) {
                                    soma = soma + 3;
                                } else
                                    if (cont == 6) {
                                        soma = soma + 10;
                                    } else 
                                        if (cont ==7) {
                                            soma = soma + 1;
                                        } else
                                            if (cont == 8) {
                                                soma = soma + 1;
                                            } else
                                                if (cont == 9) {
                                                    soma = soma + 10;
                                                } else
                                                    if (cont == 10) {
                                                        soma = soma + 3;
                                                    }
                break;
            case 'n':
                break;
            default:
                printf("A resposta não é valida. digite s-sim, n-não. \n");
                grauRisco();
                break;
        }
    
        return ;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome. You did not review the existing code ?

Comment: When you say that `setlocale()` "didn't work", how do you know, given that you just ignored the return value?

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` - since `stdin` is an input stream, the behaviour is __undefined__.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `setlocale()` expects language tags

You call `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese")`, but unfortunately the system does not expect the English name for a language, but rather a so-called [language tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_localisation#Language_tags_and_codes), a combination of ISO country and language codes. For example, if you wanted Portuguese spoken in Portugal, it would be `pt_PT`, but if you wanted Portuguese as spoken in Brazil, it would be `pt_BR`.

## `setlocale()` doesn't change how keyboard input works

The main thing `setlocale()` does is change how things like numbers and dates are printed, and it will choose the right translation file if you made your program [internationalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) using [gettext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext). However, you are not using any of the functions that would change the output based on the locale, and more importantly, `setlocale()` doesn't change how text entered on the keyboard is transmitted to your program. The latter is done by the console or terminal emulator you are using, and it isn't affected by calls to `setlocale()`. Instead, you have to make sure you are prepared to handle what the console send to your program, which brings me to:

## The character encoding matters

While you can expect most computer systems in the world to support ASCII out of the box, this only covers the letters used in English. When you want to support special characters such as Ç, ã and so on, there are multiple ways to [encode those characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). If your terminal is set for [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), then all of the Portuguese characters fit inside a single `char`, however nowadays [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is the norm, and in that encoding the non-ASCII characters will take at least two bytes to encode, which means they no longer fit in a `char`.

To support reading single characters from UTF-8 input, you will have to use [`getwc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetwc) or [`wscanf("%c", ...)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwscanf) to read the character into a `wchar_t`. However, if you want to read a whole line, like for example when asking for the full name of a patient, then you can use [`fgetws()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetws).

But to make it more confusing, you can still use `fgets()` to read a line into a string of regular `char`s, and it will still be able to read UTF-8 input correctly, however there just might not be a one-to-one mapping from each `char` in the string to a single character anymore. It's fine for things like `paciente.nome`: you read it in and you print it, but you don't really care about the individual characters. The only time you care about one character is when you read in `paciente.sexo` and when asking sim/não questions. In both these cases, the only valid answers happen to be ASCII characters (`f`/`m` and `s`/`n`), so you can actually use regular `scanf("%c", ...)` or `getchar()` here.

## Avoid long `if-else` chains

The long `if-else` chain inside `grauRisco()` should either be replaced with a `switch`-statement, like so:

```
case 's':
    cont++;

    switch(cont) {
    case 1:
        soma += 5;
        break;
    case 2:
        soma += 1;
        break;
    ...
    }
    break;
```

Or even better, use a data-driven approach, where the values to add to `soma` are stored in an array:

```
case 's':
    static const int incrementos_de_risco[10] = {5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 10, 3};
    if (cont < 10) {
        soma += incrementos_de_risco[cont++];
    }
    break;
```

## Avoid global variables

Global variables become problematic in larger programs; they pollute the global namespace, they make it harder to support multiple threads, and so on. It is best to avoid them where possible, and instead declare them as close to the scope where they are used instead, and pass (pointers to) those variables to other functions when necessary.

In the case of `grauRisco()`, I would rename it to `pedirRisco()` (if that makes sense in Portuguese) and just have it return `true` or `false` depending on whether the user answered sim or não. You can also have it print the question, like so:

```
bool pedirRisco(const char *pergunta) {
    printf("%s s-sim, n-não\n", pergunta);
    ...
    case 's':
        return true;
    case 'n':
        return false;
    ...
}
```

Then just keep a count of how many risk factors a patient has, and only when you asked all questions, convert the number of risks to a risk factor:

```
int numeroRiscos = 0;

numeroRiscos += pedirRisco("Tem Febre?");
numeroRiscos += pedirRisco("Tem dor de cabeça?");
...

static const int graus[11] = {0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 21, 22, 23, 33, 35};
int soma = graus[numeroRiscos];
```

Note that this is just doing the same as your code, but I have a suspicion that you actually wanted to assign a risk value to each symptom. In that case, I would change it to:

```
int pedirRisco(const char *pergunta, int risco) {
    printf("%s s-sim, n-não\n", pergunta);
    ...
    case 's':
        return risco;
    case 'n':
        return 0;
    ...
}

...

int soma = 0;
soma += pedirRisco("Tem Febre?", 10);
soma += pedirRisco("Tem dor de cabeça?", 1);
...
```

## Consider using a data-driven design

While the above already simplifies your code a lot, there is still a lot of repetition of code. This can be eliminated by using a more data-driven design, where you store the questions and the risk factors in an array, and then use a loop to ask all the questions and sum the risks:

```
static const struct {
    const char *pergunta,
    int risco,
} riscos[] = {
    {"Tem Febre?", 10},
    {"Tem dor de cabeça?", 1},
    ...
};

size_t nRiscos = sizeof riscos / sizeof *riscos; // number of elements in riscos[]
int soma = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < nRiscos; i++) {
    soma += pedirRisco(riscos[i].pergunta, riscos[i].risco);
}
```

The main advantage is that it is now very easy to add more questions, and you could even have it read the list of questions and risk factors from a file.

## Missing error checking

What happens if the output file cannot be opened, or if something goes wrong while trying to print the new patient record to it? You should check the return value of all I/O functions, and ideally print an error to `stderr` if something went wrong, *and* exit the program with [`EXIT_FAILURE`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status).

## Avoid using `system()`

The `system()` function is *very* expensive to use; it creates a new process which in turn parses the command you give it, and then it might even have to start another process to execute that command. Furthermore, it is not very portable, since `cls` is specific to Windows, but will not work on Linux or macOS for example.

Instead, consider printing an [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to [clear the screen using `printf()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37774983/clearing-the-screen-by-printing-a-character/37778152). This works on most systems, including recent versions of Windows. You can also opt to not clear the screen at all, and just print a two or three blank lines.